# Is using Selenium singleton driver class common practice?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[beginner] 
What are advantages of using singleton driver class over just passing driver object to methods?
What is common practice?

Answer (score 2):

Technically, both approaches you described are singleton -- remember, [singleton is just defined by restricting the instantiation of a class to one object](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/singleton-design-pattern/).

So long as you are only initializing `WebDriver` once, it doesn't really make a difference whether you are using an inherited class instance of `WebDriver`, or if you are just passing it around as a parameter in your method calls.

Now, the difference between what you described in your problem description, and the alternate method of using a `WebDriver` class variable in a base class which is inherited (rather than passed as a parameter) is a different issue. The approach you choose to take depends on what context you are using Selenium / automation for.

If you are maintaining a test suite with multiple Page Objects, multiple test files, etc., then `WebDriver` class variable is a good approach -- this is a great way to use `WebDriver` objects both efficiently and in a thread-safe manner.

However, if you are just running one long Selenium script, on an as-needed basis, it's fine to pass `WebDriver` into each method call that you make. If you end up writing *many* scripts that have to do this, it may become a bit more difficult to maintain, which is where the class variable approach mentioned earlier comes into play.

[This repository](https://github.com/harbourc/Generic_Python_UI_Auto) shows a good example of the class-variable approach, where you don't have to worry about passing `WebDriver` into every method call you make.

`base_test_fixture` implements a `WebDriver` class variable, in addition to `setUp()` and `tearDown()` methods that run before & after every test -- these methods handle initializing & destroying the `WebDriver` object.

I like this approach, because you can pass the `WebDriver` object into PageObject classes, and the PageObject instance can use `WebDriver` to perform methods. This approach eliminates the issue of having to use `WebDriver` as a parameter in all of your methods.

Apologies for the lengthy explanation -- it's difficult to break down test architecture in a few sentences, so I try to provide as much information as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong. Driver instance doesn't have to be singleton. You can create multiple instances like this.

```java
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");  

        WebDriver driver1 = new ChromeDriver();
        WebDriver driver2 = new ChromeDriver();
    }
}
```

But each instance will create a separated Webdriver session, separated browser and separated browser profile. So in some reasonable case it's necessary but really unsual.

Comment: I understand that it is possible to create more instances. I forgot to say , I use Selenium for scraping so I do not see any reason to make more then 1 instance of it. I asked the question because it became too annoying to pass driver object to methods all the time.

Comment: If you create a singleton wrapper / holder class around the webdriver you don't have to pass instance to methods just get the only one webdriver object. But then your solution will work only one thread, only one instance. It's up to you to choose the best possible solution for your problem.